# UITableViewCell and customised accessoryDisclosureIndicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I made customised accessoryDisclosureIndicator at `UITableViewCell`.
I have a background color at alternate `Table Cell` and once the customised image view (detail) is inserted for the `accessorydisclosureindicator`, the right end of the table cell's background color is changed.

How can I have background color is same?
The problem is shown in the attached image.[image]

The code is shown below.

```
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"measure_bar1.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0] ];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.968 green:0.862 blue:0.925 alpha:0.5];



    UIImageView *detail = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
    [detail setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"detail_arrow.png"]];
    [cell setAccessoryView:detail];
```

Comment: try this: `cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.968 green:0.862 blue:0.925 alpha:0.5];`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.968 green:0.862 blue:0.925 alpha:0.5];
```

to

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.968 green:0.862 blue:0.925 alpha:0.5];
```

the cell `contentView` stops right when the accessory view begins.

Take a look at this illustration:

[image]

Comment: No it doesn't display background color anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but now no more background color.

Comment: not sure why it did not work, try testing with `[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];`

Comment: Did you try, im looking up alternatives now

Comment: Yeah I tried, but looks like background layer is underneath of component and accessory. i just see thin black color border

Comment: Oh i remember this happening to me as well, i believe i ended up setting the colors in Xcode instead of code try that. U should be able to click on the view and change color